# How to create Console Application in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac?

Tags: c#, console-application, visual-studio-2022

I can't seem to understand how to create a console app project because it's not a template option. However, solutions on the internet seem to all have this option. What should I do?

[image: welcome page]

Comment: I don't use VS for Mac but I'm guessing that you should be looking under the Mac section rather than the Multiplatform section.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong category. Did you [check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-mac)? If the `Web and Console` category is missing it means you forgot to add the relevant features when installing VS Mac

Comment: If it's a .net Console App.  You might need to install Mono.  https://www.mono-project.com/download/vs/.